# How can I create pivot table in SAS?

Tags: sas

I have three columns in a dataset: `spend`, `age_bucket`, and `multiplier`.  The data looks something like...

```
spend   age_bucket  multiplier
10      18-24        2x
120     18-24        2x
1       35-54        3x
```

I'd like a dataset with the columns as the age buckets, the rows as the multipliers, and the entries as the sum (or other aggregate function) of the spend column.  Is there a `proc` to do this?  Can I accomplish it easily using `proc SQL`?

Comment: Proc tabulate is also powerful for building pivot type tables with specific aggregations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this.

```
data have;
input spend   age_bucket $ multiplier $;
datalines;

10      18-24        2x
120     18-24        2x
1       35-54        3x
10      35-54        2x
;

proc summary data=have;
var spend;
class age_bucket multiplier;
output out=temp sum=;
run;
```

First you can use `PROC SUMMARY` to calculate the aggregation, sum in this case, for the variable in question.  The `CLASS` statement gives you things to sum by.  This will calculate the N-Way sums and the output data set will contain them all.  Run the code and look at data set `temp`.

Next you can use `PROC TRANSPOSE` to pivot the table.  We need to use a `BY` statement so a `PROC SORT` is necessary.  I also filter to the aggregations you care about.

```
proc sort data=temp(where=(_type_=3));
by multiplier;
run;

proc transpose data=temp out=want(drop=_name_);
by multiplier;
var spend;
id age_bucket;
idlabel age_bucket;
run;
```

In traditional mode `35-54` is not a valid SAS variable name.  SAS will convert your columns to proper names.  The label on the variable will retain the original value.  Just be aware if you need to reference the variable later, the name has changed to be valid.

[image]