# Is there a way to automatically create multiple new variables based on one value?

Tags: sas

[image]

In my current table I have two columns. One represents the number of new cases on a given day. The other represents the number of days.

I want to create new variables representing individuals so I'd end up up with a new table.

For example:
[image]

On day 0, there was 1 patient infected so patient 1 is created. On day 1, 3 people are infected so there are 3 new patients created. I'm at a loss on even how to begin. I'm open to doing this in python if it isn't possible in SAS.

Comment: Is this a "pivot" operation? If so, https://stackoverflow.com/q/39875604/2864740 , https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings12/146-2012.pdf etc. might be relevant.

Comment: If you're using SAS for the analysis, many procs have a WEIGHT or FREQ statement that will then correctly interpret your data in the format it currently is.

Answer (score 1):

Just use an OUTPUT statement in a loop.

```
data want;
  set have;
  do i=1 to new_cases;
    patient+1;
    output;
  end;
run;
```